# XSD file ensure that an attribute of an element that occurs an unbounded number of times is NOT set exactly one time?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

My xml files have an element  with an optional attribute lang.

e.g.

```
<movie>
    <title>Lord of the Rings</title>
    <title lang="ger">Herr der Ringe</title>
    <title lang="esp">El Senor de los Anillos</title>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Game of Thrones</title>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Star War</title>
    <title lang="fra">Guerre des etoiles</title>
    <title lang="ger">Krieg der Sterne</title>
</movie>
```

Is there any way to ensure in the xml schema that every movie has exactly one  without any attribute "lang" and if there are any more titles, they need to have this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Michael Kay's approach, it's simple.

Though meanwhile I tried an approach with `xs:assert` (warning: requires XSD 1.1, but this is supported by [at least Xerces, with PsychoPath](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2) and [Saxon](http://saxonica.com)) and didn't want to withhold that from you. The idea is to simply leave the attribute optional, but to assert whether the first item has it set. I'm not sure whether this can be expressed simpler, but here goes:

```
<xs:element name="movie" type="t:tpMovie" />

<xs:complexType name="tpMovie">
    <xs:sequence>            
        <xs:element name="title"  minOccurs="1" type="t:tpTitle" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>        
    <xs:assert test="t:title[1][not(@lang)]" />
    <xs:assert test="every $t in t:title[1]/following-sibling::t:title satisfies not(empty($t/@lang))" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="tpTitle">
    <xs:attribute name="lang" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

With the following input:

```
<movie .. ns removed for brevity..>    
    <title />
    <title lang="en"/>
    <title lang="es" />
    <title  />
</movie>
```

or:

```
<movie ..ns removed for brevity..>    
    <title lang="de"/>
    <title lang="en"/>
    <title lang="es" />
</movie>
```

You will receive an assertion error.

While the following succeeds:

```
<movie ..ns removed for brevity..>    
    <title />
    <title lang="de"/>
    <title lang="en"/>
    <title lang="es" />
</movie>
```

### Update (new req., see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526425/xsd-file-ensure-that-an-attribute-of-an-element-that-occurs-an-unbounded-number/32528374#comment53147374_32528374))

If you want to test for at least one title without `@lang` and the rest must have a `lang` attribute, then you can write this (remove the other assertion):

```
<xs:assert test="count(t:title[not(@lang)]) = 1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but unfortunately there is already a large number of XML fiels (which dont have an default "lang attribute") and I need to stay consistent with these already existing files.

That's way I need a schema that determines that there is always exactly one <name> without any "lang attribute" plus `zero to unbound` <names> with a "lang attribute".

I guess the answer can be achieved with Schematron, but i dont know how.

Comment: @MrLang, that's why I showed you a schema that does exactly that. Just validate your input against it and it will reject anything that does not fit that requirement. My code _does not set a default `lang` attribute_

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that at first. But now I have another problem. Somehow I can't test the code because all I get is this error message: `Description Resource Path Location Type
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'namesType' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often. mySchema.xsd /myProject/src/main/resources line 114 XML Schema Problem`. Somehow I can't figure out how to use XSD Version 1.1 (or this even the issue?)

Comment: @MrLang, you need to [specify XSD 1.1, here explained by one of the lead editors of the spec](http://www.blackmesatech.com/2009/04/vcdoc.html).

Comment: @MrLang, normally I'd always mention if I show a solution with XSD 1.1. Apparently not this time. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks again! But is know it works only if the very first `<title>` has no attribute, but it also should work if the second or third `<title>` is the one without the attribute. Could it work to count the nodes with and without attributes and restrict that the count of nodes without an attribute as to be `1` and the rest hast to be `all - 1`? Or something like that?

Comment: @MrLang, I have added an update to the question, where we simply count the number of elements that does not have a lang attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite what you asked for, but it might be what you want: I think that you can handle this by defining a default value for the attribute (e.g. "en") and then checking that all the values are unique. You can define a default on the `xs:attribute` declaration, and you can define uniqueness within the declaration of the `movie` element using

```
<xs:unique name="unique-lang">
  <xs:selector xpath="title"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@lang"/>
</xs:unique>
```

This won't stop the default value being explicitly present on the English version of the title, but I assume you can live with that.

I would recommend using the international standard codes for languages rather than making up your own.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found something that worked for me: 
`<xs:assert test="(count(title) = 0) or (count(title[@*]) + 1 = count(title))" />`

Comment: Looks like your answer  violates your own requirement: _"Is there any way to ensure in the xml schema that every movie has exactly one without any attribute "lang""_. As `<title foo="ru" />` will (may! depends on rest of xsd) succeed and no titles at all will succeed. If your requirements changed, that's fine, but if not, be aware of the difference ;). Any rec that does a `count(xxx)` should instead go into `minOccurs` or `maxOccurs`, it will give better error messages.